# Facebook page content in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I want to render each posts from my facebook page to my website, using frontend JavaScript + HTML + CSS code? Is this possible?

Please share me some tutorial or reference for doing this.

## update

So far I have trried following:

I went to following URL : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/

And try to do as it mentioned for JavaScript SDK

> Step 1: Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening body tag.
> Step 3: Place this code wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

I don't know why there is no **Step 2**

Also after doing this also, my page is not loaidng content.

Comment: First, you should register your site to facebook. After this, let's continue to discuss.

Comment: have you tried this yet?

Comment: I never know that there is something like that, registering site to facebook!!

Comment: @suzan I have updated the details with what I have tried

Comment: there is a step 2 but not step 3.

Comment: Started loading. Its failing to load sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these process:

1. Go to [facebook page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/)
2. Fill in the form giving the url to your page
3. Click on `Get the code`
4. You will get two options to show the FB page details

   i)  using SDK

   ii) using iFrame
5. Select any one option and follow the steps provided.

There you go. Your Facebook timeline in your website.